# Block with delay and callback Objective-C

Tags: callback, delay, objective-c-blocks

I have a local var button that appears for 3 seconds and then disappears. In the past I have made two functions for this: one to make it visible and then within that 'perform selector after delay' to another function to then remove it. But then I need variables etc.

I'd like to take advantage of blocks to keep variables in scope etc and just have one method for this.

Possible?

Answer (score 0):

Think you can use dispatch_after. Remember that all UI interactions must be the on the main queue:

```
dispatch_time_t time =dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, interval * NSEC_PER_SEC)
dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
  //dissapear procedure
});
```